# Closed form of a recursive integral

Tags: calculus, integration, recursion

I have a recursive integral,

$f(T) = f(0) + \frac{\gamma}{2} \int_{0}^T f(t)^2 dt$

where $f(0) \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $T \in \mathbb{R}^+$ all take known numerical values.

Is there some way to convert the above equation for $f(T)$ to closed form? I'm completely stumped. It resembles an equation of motion in some sense but that's not helped me.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Hint: Differentiating the equation gives
$$ f'(T)=\frac{\gamma}{2}f^2(T). $$

Comment: I'll be honest I'm not exactly seeing how this hint helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiating the equation gives
$$ f'(T)=\frac{\gamma}{2}f^2(T). $$
So one has
$$ \frac{f'(T)}{f^2(T)}=\frac{\gamma}{2} $$
which implies
$$ \int\frac{df(T)}{f^2(T)}=\frac{\gamma}{2}T+C $$
or
$$ -\frac{1}{f(T)} = \frac{\gamma}{2}T+C. $$
Thus
$$ f(T)=-\frac{1}{\frac{\gamma}{2}T+C}. $$
But $f(0)=-\frac{1}{C}$, one has $C=-\frac{1}{f(0)}$ and hence
$$ f(T)=-\frac{1}{\frac{\gamma}{2}T-\frac{1}{f(0)}}=-\frac{f(0)}{\frac{\gamma}{2}f(0)T-1}. $$

Comment: Awesome, all looks correct to me, clearly I need to try to remember some more calculus from school because it's so simple in retrospect!